# Variables getting transformed when changing visibility in LESS

Tags: javascript, css, less

So I am trying to get class2 going. The reason btw I am trying to do this, is to use this snippet to use shadows :

```
.box-shadow(@shadowA, @shadowB:X, ...){
    @props: ~`"@{arguments}".replace(/[\[\]]|\,\sX/g, '')`;
    -webkit-box-shadow: @props;
       -moz-box-shadow: @props;
         -o-box-shadow: @props;
            box-shadow: @props;
}
```

but this snippet above is just explanation why I am posting this in general.

The question is why is `.class` and `.class2` not the same?

You can use [dopefly's LESS converter to check it out](http://www.dopefly.com/LESS-Converter/less-converter.html)

```
.class{
 .f1(a,b,c,d);
}


.f1(@t1, @t2:X,...){
 @props: ~`"@{arguments}".replace(/[\[\]]|\,\sX/g, '')`;
 background: @props;
}




.class2{
 .f2(a,b,c,d);
}
.f2(@t1, @t2:X,...){
 .f2helper(@arguments);
 background: @props;
}

.f2helper(@t1, @t2:X,...){
 @props: ~`"@{arguments}".replace(/[\[\]]|\,\sX/g, '')`;
}
```

It btw becomes this:

```
.class {
  background: a, b, c, d;
}
.class2 {
  background: a b c d;
}
```

Bonus question: replace is not listed in LESS' definition of available built in functions - so what function set is really provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First, a Better Way?

You no longer need to resort to inline javascript to get the props. Javascript, by the way, is what the `replace` function is... it is not a built in LESS function, but LESS can access the javascript environment just as the code you offered is doing with the backtick (`` ` ``) marks.

Do this, assuming you want two specifically named variables and then a final variable to catch all other list items. Note the use of the semicolon `;` in the *call* to the `.f1` mixin as the parameter delimiter. This causes the final `@props` comma separated list to be interpreted as such:

```
.f1(@t1, @t2:X, @props){
 background: @t1, @t2, @props;
}

.class{
 .f1(a; b; c, d;);
}
```

If you do not need the first two variables to be individually called (or do not want defaults set), then this works:

```
.f1(@props){
 background: @props;
}

.class{
 .f1(a, b, c, d;);
}
```

### Second, as to Why the Difference

I believe why the two do not function the same is because this call:

```
.f2helper(@arguments);
```

Ends up passing the series of arguments as a *single* argument to `.f2helper`, which then does not insert the commas between (what you think are) the separate arguments, whereas the `.f1` mixin is processing the *multiple* arguments passed to it as multiple ones and inserting the commas between them.

Answer (score 1):

The value of a variable (e.g `@arguments`) is never interpreted as a list of mixin parameters, it's always passed as one parameter. Well, it's easier to see what happens if you print out the value of `@arguments` for each mixin:

```
.class {
    .f1(a, b, c, d);
}

.f1(@t1, @t2: X, ...) {
    args: @arguments; // here you have four parameters, js: [a, b, c, d]
}

.class2 {
    .f2(a, b, c, d);
}
.f2(@t1, @t2: X, ...) {
    .f2helper(@arguments);
}

.f2helper(@t1, @t2: X, ...) {
    args: @arguments; // here you have two parameters, js: [a b c d, X]
}
```

Result:

```
.class {
  args: a b c d;
}
.class2 {
  args: a b c d X;
}
```

I.e. your regex does not work in `.f2` as you expect it to.

---

And as mentioned by @ScottS such hacks no longer make sense in LESS since you can do:

```
.box-shadow(@value) {
    box-shadow: @value;
}

test {
    .box-shadow(a, b, c, d;); // notice ';' at the end of parameters
}
```

Result:

```
test {
    box-shadow: a, b, c, d;
}
```

See [Parametric Mixins](https://github.com/less/less-docs/blob/master/content/features/mixins-parametric.md#mixins-with-multiple-parameters) for more details.

---

> #### so what function set is really provided?

See [Functions](https://github.com/less/less-docs/tree/master/content/functions).

Comment: actually the function replace is not listed there as far as i know, that's why the question. Seems like all basic javascript functions are provided somehow

Comment: There're built-in LESS [functions](https://github.com/less/less-docs/blob/master/content/Overview.md#functions) (they are all listed in the docs I linked above), these functions are native part of the LESS and can be used directly e.g. `width: pi();`. But it is also possible to use *any* javascript code (including *any* javascript functions) via "[inline javascript](https://github.com/less/less-docs/blob/a2e46284ef9ad7beb3831343f3140c7918b641b6/content/doc.md#javascript-evaluation)" statements (note though this is [not recommended](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/939)).

Comment: Or in other words: `replace` is not a LESS function, `"@{arguments}".replace(/[\[\]]|\,\sX/g, '')` in your exampe is just plain JavaScript code (except `@{arguments}` string is substituted with `@arguments` variable value).